# How to write the code to use a checkbox to hide multiple columns not in order in the google sheets script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am from a non-computer background trying to execute a small code and am sharing some inputs which I think are relevant to this query (based on my evening of research). Can please someone help me create this code to execute the "purpose"?

Purpose- Use a checkbox to hide some columns which are not in order or next to one another.

Range in question: A:S

Checkbox location: Cell- "K47"

If above is true, Hide columns- A, B, D, F, G, H, I, L, M, P, Q, R, and S

If above is false, Show all columns A to S

Sheet name- "USER"

Regards,
Kavita

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the inputs guys. I had a friend help me and here's what I got.

Note, ["ABHISHEK", "MITESH", "KAVITA", "MEENA","SUNIL"] are the sheet names where i wanted the switch to work . the switch location has been changed from K47 to E1

```js
// @ts-nocheck
function onEdit()
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

["ABHISHEK", "MITESH", "KAVITA", "MEENA","SUNIL"].forEach(function (s) { var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);

  var st =sheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
  
  if(st == true)
  {
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("A:B")); 
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("D:D"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("F:I"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("L:M"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("P:S"));

  }

  else
  {
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("A:B"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("D:D"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("F:I"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("L:M"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("P:S"));  
  }

}
)
}
```

Comment: This does certainly work, but note that this is hiding/unhiding the columns everytime you edit the sheet (hiding the columns already hidden or showing the columns already shown) even if you are not ticking/unticking the checkbox. I recommend you use the `event` object and limit your `onEdit` to specific cell like the other answer has shown. The other answer only hide/unhide when the checkbox is changed, not when other cells are edited.

Answer (score 0):

In the Script Editor, write a function (a simple trigger) for `onEdit()`. In your code, evaluate if the checkbox was checked using `sheet.getRange("K47")` and `range.getValue()` (the sheet can be obtained using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('USER')`). Contain within an `if-else` statement the actions you listed and then run the script once to authorize. For resources on how to further translate your pseudocode into Apps Script, I would suggest https://www.w3schools.com/js/ and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 0):

User86530 points you to the correct direction. But I would prefer using the `event` object.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var range = e.range;
  var value = e.value;
  // if sheet name is 'USER' and edited cell is 'K47'
  if(spreadsheet.getSheetName() == 'USER' && range.getRow() == 47 && range.getColumn() == 11) {
    sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('USER');
    if(value == "TRUE") {
      // Hide columns
      sheet.hideColumns(1, 2); // A-B
      sheet.hideColumns(4, 1); // D
      sheet.hideColumns(6, 4); // F-I
      sheet.hideColumns(12, 2); // L-M
      sheet.hideColumns(16, 4); // P-S
    }
    else {
      sheet.showColumns(1, 19); // A-S
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Add the code above as script for the sheet, save and try to edit the cell right away.
- This will only get triggered if `K47` is edited on `USER`

#### Resource:

- [Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: @User86530, that is where you are wrong. If you test it thoroughly by doing `typeof e.value`, it will return a string. If that happens, then `if('FALSE')` will return `true`. That is what we do not want to happen. `e.value` is a string, not a boolean object.

Comment: @User86530, `getValue()` returns a typed variable whereas `e.value` doesn't. Wasn't able to test other data like date but as far as the checkbox is concerned, it does return a string in `e.value`