# 2 script hide columns based a cell value

Tags: google-sheets

how to make this script works on different sheet with different trigger?
simple is make same script run twice

original script works on many sheets and hiding many columns
on the 2nd script i make it simple, and reverse function.
with current condition, original script works fine, and 2nd script doesnt work

[Script Source](http:////%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275584/how-to-write-the-code-to-use-a-checkbox-to-hide-multiple-columns-not-in-order-in)

```
function onEdit() {
  onEdit1();
  onEdit2();
}


function onEdit1() // Original Script
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

["Calc", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3","Sheet4"].forEach(function (s) { var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s); /// works on many sheets

  var st =sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(); //trigger cell
  
  if(st == false) //trigger word
  {
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("W:Z")); 
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AA:AK"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AL:AN"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AO:AO"));
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AP:AP"));

  }

  else
  {
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("W:Z"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("A:K"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("AL:AN"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("AO:AO"));
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("AP:AP"));  
  }

})}


function onEdit2() /// 2nd script
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

["Duo","Sheet1","Sheet2"].forEach(function (s) { var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s); /// bisa di banyak sheet

  var st =sheet.getRange("AC5").getValue(); //trigger cell
  
  if(st == True) //trigger word
  {
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange("AU:BH")); // i Reverse hide unhide
    
  }

  else
  {
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AU:BH")); //here too
  
  }

})}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from `how to make this script works on different sheet with different trigger? simple is make same script run twice`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: different sheet need to hide/unhide diffferent columns based on each trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

In JavaScript (and therefore, in Apps Script), the boolean values are `true` and `false`.

You are using `True` instead, with capital `T`, so most probably it's throwing an error because it's undefined (you can take a look at the `Executions` tab in your script in order to check this).

#### Solution:

In your `onEdit2` function, change this:

```
if(st == True) //trigger word
```

To this:

```
if(st == true) //trigger word
```

#### Reference:

- [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Comment: done it, on script 1 type false/False/FALSE it works but script 2 it doesnt responding [Link to try] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZlsiMjG-Sw9wVBlLwWpLB3JA0FHC2w8wddCpFGQoJ6c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @yoenoess The script stops before reaching `onEdit2` because it is trying to access ranges in non-existent sheets, because if the sheet name doesn't exist `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);` will return `null`, and `null` doesn't have a method `getRange`. Either implement a `try...catch` or don't add non-existent sheets to your list (in your test spreadsheet there are only `Calc` and `Duo`, and in your list there are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4`).

Comment: awsome it works like magic, thankyouuu